# Eclipce не создаёт Activity мастером (через интерфейс)

Tags: android-sdk, android, eclipse, activity

Раньше такой проблемы не было - при создании приложения генерировалось MainActivity.java, activity_main.xml и запись в манифесте. Теперь же ни при создании нового приложения (с галочкой Create Activity), ни при добавлении Activity через Ctrl+N ни происходит ничего - папки src и res/layout остаются пусты. Пробовал запускать от имени Администратора, менял min и target SDK в манифесте, на всякий случай скачал все Build-Tools - не помогло.

Можно конечно добавлять Activity руками, создавая класс и всё такое, но это же не дело!
Подскажите почему может не работать? Заранее благодарен.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Проблема решена. Здесь описано решение: [ADT will not allow creation of Android Activity](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22190578/adt-will-not-allow-creation-of-android-activity)